# Solving a PDE - do you have an idea?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> > Do you have an idea how to solve
> >     $$
> > v_{\xi\eta}=\frac{1}{2} v_{\xi}\cdot\xi?
> > $$

First I thought of using
$$
v_{\xi\eta}=v_{\eta\xi},
$$
substituting $z:=v_{\xi}$ and then getting
$$
\frac{dz}{d\eta}=\frac{1}{2}z\cdot\xi.
$$
First I thought that I can solve this by separation of variables, but it is not the needed form to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
v_{\xi \eta} &= \frac 12 v_\xi \xi \\
\frac {v_{\xi \eta}}{v_\xi} &= \frac 12 \xi \\
\left( \ln v_\xi \right )_\eta &= \frac 12 \xi \\
\ln v_\xi &= \frac 12 \xi \eta + C_1(\xi) \\
v_\xi &= e^{C_1(\xi) + \frac 12 \xi \eta} \\
v &= \int e^{C_1(\xi) + \frac 12 \xi \eta} d\xi + C_2 (\eta)
\end{align}

Comment: Okay, thats what I have. But I set $\exp(C_1(\xi))=:C_2(\xi)$, getting $v(\xi,\eta)=\int_a^{\xi}C_2(\tau)\exp(\frac{1}{2}\tau\eta)\, d\tau + C_3(\eta)$ where $a\in\Omega, C_2, C_3\in C^1(\Omega)$ are arbirtrary and $\Omega$ is the domain on which the PDE is valid.

Comment: @math12 $\exp(C_1 (\xi)) \ne C_2(\eta)$. $\xi$ and $\eta$ are two independent variables.

Comment: Sorry I meant $C_2(\xi):=\exp(C_1(\xi))$.

Comment: @math12 Yes, you can do that, but you still need to integrate $C_1(\xi)$, so you cannot just say it's $\frac 2 \eta e^{\frac 12 \xi \eta}$ as you accepted as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

These ($v,z,\xi,\eta$) are scalars? (otherwise the pde is 'derivative of vector = scalar' which doesn't make sense)

In this case, the equation *is* separable, and the solution is $z = e^{\frac{1}{2}\xi\eta}$, and $v$ is then something like $\dfrac{2}{\eta}e^{\frac{1}{2}\xi\eta} + g(\eta)$.

EDIT: as kaster points out, I forgot to include a $C(\xi)$ term when taking the first anti-derivative. His answer gives the correct approach for solving this.

Comment: Yes, they are indeed scalars. Ah, separation of variables is possible when considering $\xi$ as a parameter and the ODE only in $\eta$?

Comment: You forgot an arbitrary function $C(\xi)$ when integrated over $\eta$.

Comment: Whoops, yes, you're correct. OP, you should consider kaster's solution the correct one.